# exec() function with listing environment variables

Tags: c, linux, shell, environment

This code is for program "echoall":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int i;
        char **ptr;
        extern char **environ;

        for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
                printf("argv[%d]: %s \n", i, argv[i]);

        for(ptr=environ; *ptr!=0; ptr++)
        {
                printf("%s \n", *ptr);
        }

        exit(0);
}
```

and this code is for program that using `exec()` call:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char *env_init[]={"USER=unknown", "PATH=/tmp", NULL};

int main(void)
{
        //extern char **environ;
        //char **ptr;
        pid_t pid;

        //for(ptr=environ; *ptr!=0; ptr++)
        //      printf("%s\n", *ptr);

        if((pid==fork()) < 0 )
        {
                printf("fork() error");
                exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid==0)
        {
                if(execle("/root/apue/chapter_8/echoall", "echoall", "myarg1", "MY ARG2", (char*)0, env_init)<0)
                {
                        printf("execle() error");
                        exit(1);
                }
        }

        if(waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) < 0)
        {
                printf("wait error");
                exit(1);
        }

        if((pid=fork())<0)
        {
                printf("fork() error");
                exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid==0)
        {
                if(execlp("echoall", "only 1 arg", (char*)0)<0)
                {
                        printf("execlp() error");
                        exit(1);
                }
        }

        exit(0);
}
```

When we use `exec()` functions which receive environment list arguments, these environment lists are the executed program's environment lists(in here, first `fork()`).

But when we use `exec()` functions that does not receive environment list arguments, parent's `char **environ` is used for executed program automatically. (in here, second `fork()`)

So, the result should be that first "echoall" program's environments are:

`USER=unknwon`
`PATH=/tmp`

and, second "echoall" program's environments are same as parent's environment lists.
But, my result is shown same as first "echoall" program's environment lists:

`USER=unknown`
`PATH=/tmp`

I execute program which is using `fork()`(not "echoall" program) on the shell prompt. So second "echoall" program should output environment lists same as the shell.(Because program which is using `fork()` also inherit shell's environment lists).

What's the problem here?

And, also when program using `fork()` on the above erase comment(which means it shows its environment lists.), the `waitpid()` function return `-1`, so I get error? why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After chasing around glibc for a while, I finally noticed what gcc had been trying to tell me:

```
2.c: In function 'main':
2.c:22:16: warning: 'pid' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
         else if(pid==0)
```

The code above has `if((pid==fork()) < 0 )` which should be `if ((pid=fork()) < 0)`.  Once I changed that, everything worked as expected...

```
$ env -i A=1 ./2
argv[0]: echoall 
argv[1]: myarg1 
argv[2]: MY ARG2 
USER=unknown 
PATH=/tmp 

argv[0]: echoall 
argv[1]: only 1 arg 
A=1
```